# ADMOB application showing only one add always, how to change the advertisements?

Tags: iphone, ipad, admob

i have used ADMOB application in my program, and everytime i run the application , it shows only single google samsung galaxy tablet add, how does this actuallt works, also how to change the advertisements?

Answer (score 1):

Changing add is not in your hands. Though you can check this by a hack. Create an in-house ad with say 70% and run the app. You can see your add appearing 70% of the time, and the rest of the time other ads from admob.