# Android only one admob ad is showing

Tags: android, ads

I recently got the admob ads working correctly,  I tested it through:

```
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            //.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            //.addTestDevice("INSERT_YOUR_HASHED_DEVICE_ID_HERE")
            .build();
```

The .addtestDevice worked for the Adrequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR.  I received a test ad when that was not in comments.  I took it out because I just wanted to see what would happen.  I am only seeing one ad being displayed and refreshed constantly.  Is there a way to have different ads be shown?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you're only seeing one live add, that's up to google (or your other providers) as to which ad is being shown.  See [ADMOB application showing only one add always, how to change the advertisements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657402/admob-application-showing-only-one-add-always-how-to-change-the-advertisements)

Comment: Ok so then I won't worry if i only see one ad because that does mean it can and will change ads randomly or as it pleases?

Comment: Pretty much.  One app of mine tends to show one add repeatedly.  I turned off testing on my dev phone and just let it run for a while and others started showing up.  As long as you saw a live ad, it's working.

Comment: Also is there any point or any good in adding new ad networks from the AdMob site?

Comment: More content, and more variety of content.

Comment: Thank you, one last question..which ad networks would you recommend adding?

Comment: That is entirely up to you.